# How to fail a build that has compiler warnings with Tycho

Tags: tycho

I have read that [Tycho 0.22 can reuse JDT compiler preferences](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.22) that are stored along with the project.

Now I would like to fail the build if the compiler encounters warnings as configured with the project settings. Can Tycho be configured to achieve this?

**Update 2016-11-29**:
I am looking for a solution to exactly [this question on the Tycho mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg07154.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `-err:all` compiler argument:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${tychoVersion}</version>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArgument>-err:all</compilerArgument>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See also:

- [Same question on mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg07156.html)
- [How to configure warning settings](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/FAQ#How_to_configure_warning.2Ferror_settings_of_the_OSGi_compiler.3F)
- [Warnings can not be suppressed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508344)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The suggested `compilerArgument` treats *all* problems as errors.  However, I am looking for a means to let the build fail if one of the warnings configured in the project settings is encountered. I.e. I have the same question as in the link to the mailing list.